# Вывести PNG с прозрачными областями

Tags: android, bitmap, png

У меня есть PNG с прозрачным фоном. Пытаюсь его нарисовать в `Canvas` через `Bitmap`, но вместо прозрачного фона отображается белый.

Если попробовать вставить этот же PNG через `ImageView`, то получается то же самое.

Можно ли как-то убрать этот белый фон и сделать его прозрачным?

Comment: В вопросе не хватает: скриншотов, разметки или кода (если вставляете программно). А еще я бы перепроверил файл, вдруг он реально без альфа-канала.

Comment: Разметку приложите

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такую разметку

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_cam"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/navi_cam_on_svetofor" />
```